# Swift 3 Get Notification Data

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3

I'm trying to get the data out of a notification in swift 3, using this tutorial: [Developing Push Notifications for iOS 10](https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-push-notifications-for-ios-10/) Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
private func getAlert(notification: [NSObject:AnyObject]) -> (String, String) {
    let aps = notification["aps"] as? [String:AnyObject]
    let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String:AnyObject]
    let title = alert?["title"] as? String
    let body = alert?["body"] as? String
    return (title ?? "-", body ?? "-")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Ambiguous+reference+to+member+subscript) post?

Comment: @Eeshwar Yes Checked a lot of them, none of them worked

Comment: Please post your code as actual code, not as an image.

Comment: There you go @rmaddy

Comment: Hint: Lookup `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in the documentation and check the type of the `userInfo` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `notification` is declared as a dictionary with keys of type `NSObject`. But you attempt to access that dictionary with a key of type `String`. `String` is not an `NSObject`. One solution is to cast your `String` to `NSString`.

Fixing that presents another error which is fixed on the next line. So your code ends up like this:

```
private func getAlert(notification: [NSObject:AnyObject]) -> (String, String) {
    let aps = notification["aps" as NSString] as? [String:AnyObject]
    let alert = aps?["alert"] as? [String:AnyObject]
    let title = alert?["title"] as? String
    let body = alert?["body"] as? String
    return (title ?? "-", body ?? "-")
}
```

Having said all of that, that tutorial has a lot of mistakes and uses the wrong parameter types in many places. This `getAlert` method should not be using `NSObject`. It should be `String`.

Comment: The notification `userInfo` dictionary in Swift 3 is `[AnyHashable : Any]`, a standard JSON dictionary is `[String : Any]`. The OP should not use outdated types.

Comment: @vadian Agreed. That's why I made the last statement in my answer. The tutorial has a lot of issues and propagates the wrong data types all over the place. The bulk of my answer directly addressed the cause of the error for the current code and proposed one solution to that specific issue. Of course, as I stated at the end, the better solution is to use the correct types.